# how to externally trigger reactivity in VueJS for a dropdown menu

Tags: vue.js, vue-reactivity

There is a case where I need to trigger a change in a VueJS-managed component from outside VueJS.

I have found I can easily do this on a checkbox by triggering  or calling its `click()` property, but I can't do the same thing with either a `input[type=text]` or a `select` element.

The jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/q2zv5gz1/5/)

I have looked in the VueJS documentation on how reactivity works but don't understand how to make it happen here.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the Vue instance in a global variable (`window.vueApp = new Vue({...})`) first and change the value by doing something like `vueApp.dataValue = ...`

Edited your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/q2zv5gz1/6/

**Save the Vue instance in a global variable**

```
window.vueApp = new Vue({ ...
```

**and inside onclick:**

```
  <!-- totally unrelated to Vue! -->
  <button onclick="vueApp.selectValue = vueApp.selectValue === 'alpha' ? 'beta' : 'alpha' " >
   change select
  </button>
    <button onclick="vueApp.checkboxValue = !vueApp.checkboxValue" >
   change checkbox
  </button>
  <button onclick="vueApp.textValue = Math.random()">
  change input
  </button>
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you want a way in which the elements should have no knowledge of how Vue was implemented, you gotta find a way to properly trigger the input event on the input elements programmatically.

To trigger an event, you may use

```
.dispatchEvent(new Event('eventname'));
```

After playing around with it : https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/q2zv5gz1/7/

`change` event works for select

```
document.getElementById('select').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

`input` event works for text

```
document.getElementById('text').dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

**NOTE:** This probably won't work reliably across different browser. As this is trying to programmatically simulate a user action. I think different browsers would handle user action differently.

Comment: Yes, that does work, and I was aware of that but it seems kludgy.  It's just very tantalyzing that I can do this with a checkbox and it registers with `VueJS`s reactivity mechanism, but I can't do it with a text or select.  Your method means I need to know something about the way Vue was implemented :)

Comment: @OliverWilliams added another solution. but I don't think it's reliable. just my 2 cents